# If A Changeling becomes a Succubus, can she fly?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, shapeshifting, changeling

If a Changeling becomes a Succubus, can she fly?

More broadly, does a Changeling gain the racial abilities of any race he or she is mimicking?

Comment: You can only obscure or add minor details and can never change your body type. I'm not entirely sure what that means (so this will not be an answer), but most DMs I had agree on "no shapes with wings".

Answer (score 18):

**I'm afraid not**. As detailed on page 13 of the *Eberron Campaign Setting* for 3.5e D&D, the changeling's *Minor Change Shape* grants them

> the supernatural ability to alter their appearance as though using a *disguise self* spell that affects their bodies but not their possessions.

The mechanical effect of the changeling's power is that of *disguise self*, save that it's not an illusion. As *[disguise self](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/disguiseSelf.htm)* does not grant racial abilities, neither does the changeling racial trait. The wings produced are cosmetic; they don't have the ability to bring the changeling aloft.

Comment: No, but she is much hotter.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up giving the Changeling flight as a base ability through "Dragonborn" background or some such.